# Crossbrowser of my site

Tags: google-chrome, safari, cross-browser, opera, mozilla

I make an website("http://duco.md/"),how can make it crossbrowsing.
When i access the site with safari it doesn't display the text from some blocks.
What can I do?  Thanks

Comment: a) Learn to use valid HTML and CSS. Then you won't have (m)any problems with recent versions of major browsers (if you want to support older IE versions, that's a whole other can of worms...). b) If you come across any _specific_ issues that you don't know how to solve, search the web (including SO) for a solution (most likely there'll be an answer for it here), and if you still can't get it to work, reduce your issue to a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it as a question here. Sorry, but you can't expect an answer to all your cross-browser issues based on a vague question.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use Chrome Extension - BrowserStack Local for cross-browsers
  testing.
- Use Font Book application and validate all fonts.
- Remove or replace corrupted third party fonts which causes
  font rendering issues.

Comment: I know.But I don't know how to solve al the compatiblity of the site with al browsers. ((